# Optimize linq query with count()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have the following query that works fine

```
var myList = (from p in db.full


                      group p by p.object into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new StringIntType
                      {
                          str = g.Key,

                          nbr = g.Count()
                      }).Take(50).ToList();
```

The problem is that it's a bit slow due to the fact that i'm using count(), which is translated to count(*).
I need to know if is there a way to use count(object),

Here is what i got in sql server profiler

```
  exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (50) 
  [Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
  [Project1].[object] AS [object], 
  [Project1].[C1] AS [C2]
  FROM ( SELECT 
      [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [object], 
    1 AS [C2]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[object], AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM (SELECT 
[full].[mc_host_class] AS [mc_host_class], 
[full].[event_handle] AS [event_handle], 
[full].[mc_host_address] AS [mc_host_address], 
[full].[mc_object_class] AS [mc_object_class], 
[full].[mc_object] AS [mc_object], 
[full].[mc_incident_time] AS [mc_incident_time], 
[full].[date_reception] AS [date_reception], 
[full].[status] AS [status], 
[full].[mc_owner] AS [mc_owner], 
[full].[msg] AS [msg], 
[full].[duration] AS [duration], 
[full].[repeat_count] AS [repeat_count], 
[full].[mc_date_modification] AS [mc_date_modification], 
[full].[event_class] AS [event_class], 
[full].[bycn_ticket_remedy] AS [bycn_ticket_remedy], 
[full].[mc_host] AS [mc_host], 
[full].[acknowledge_by] AS [acknowledge_by], 
[full].[acknowledge_by_time] AS [acknowledge_by_time], 
[full].[assigned_by] AS [assigned_by], 
[full].[assigned_to] AS [assigned_to], 
[full].[assigned_by_time] AS [assigned_by_time], 
[full].[closed_b            y] AS [closed_by], 
[full].[closed_by_time] AS [closed_by_time], 
[full].[blacked_out] AS [blacked_out], 
[full].[bycn_liaison_type] AS [bycn_liaison_type], 
[full].[bycn_liaison_debit] AS [bycn_liaison_debit], 
[full].[cause] AS [cause], 
[full].[mc_location] AS [mc_location], 
[full].[mc_parameter] AS [mc_parameter]
FROM [dbo].[full] AS [full]) AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[object], 
        )  AS [GroupBy1]
     )  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7),@p__linq__1 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='2015-03-14 00:00:00',@p__linq__1='2015-04-15 00:00:00'
```

Comment: In your case I think SqlProfiler could help. It seems that generated query is quite simple so I'm not sure there is any opportunity to optimize like adding indexes or other performance tricks in sql.

Comment: hmm, `nbr = g.Select(a => 1).Count()`?

Comment: @Jenea in sql profiler it counts all columns of the table which takes too much time .

Comment: The innermost SELECT in the translated query seems unnecessary. Is there any way to say to linq to not generate it?

Comment: In my code or in generated code in sql server profiler ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `Order by` clause from above query and then to sort list: `myList.Sort();?`

Comment: Unfortunatly even if i avoid it in the Order by clause, it will stay at the select statement, so it the long count will be executed any way.

Comment: @drexdrex in the generated code, I know little of linq but the generated SQL statament is something like SELECT a, b FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable) c GROUP BY a, in that case the inner query can be eliminated (SELECT a, b FROM myTable GROUP BY a), but I don't know if linq can do that

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps couple optimisations can do the trick:

- Do the take first, before selecting
- Count groups only once using a let keyword

So metacode (this code written in notepad and won't compile!)

```
var topFifty = (
    from p in db.full   
    group p by p.object into g
    let groupedCount = g.Count()
    orderby groupedCount descending 
    select p.key, groupedCount
    )
    .Take(50).ToList();

var topFifty.Select(x => new StringIntType
    {
        str = x.Key,
        nbr = x.Count
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm posting how query is translated in sql profiler

Comment: We cant do the first part of code without select clause.

Comment: @drexdrex and how about selecting just a key and the count?